# How to call external Jinja2 environment

Tags: python, django-templates, jinja2, template-engine

I'm trying to call an external module to get a template rendered. The external module uses Jenja2 environment to render the template.

The code in the external module looks something like this:

```
def get_content():
    _jinja_env = Environment(
        loader=PackageLoader('mypkg'))
    content = _jinja_env.get_template("foo.html").render()
    return content
```

However, when I try to call get_content() from my Python module, the _jinja_env could not find the foo.html file. It looks like the _jinja_env's module path was pointing to my Python module instead. Is there a way to work around this issue?

One solution I can think of is to use gitsubtree instead of using the Python module way, but hopefully there is a better way than that.